# Is it possible to make a Java annotation's value mandatory?

Tags: java, annotations

Java allows the definition of values in annotations, for example:

```
public @interface MyAnnotation {
    int MyValue();
}
```

Although it is possible to set a default value for the `MyValue` annotation, I was wondering whether it is possible to make it mandatory. What I mean is forcing the user to provide a value for `MyValue` when annotating a class or field.

I went through the documentation but could not find anything. Does anyone have a solution to this issue or is it just impossible to make an annotation's value mandatory?

Comment: It should be noted that the return type of `MyValue` is only permitted to be a "primitive type, String, Class, annotation, enumeration...or 1-dimensional arrays thereof."

Answer (score 109, accepted):

If you do not specify a default value, it is mandatory. For your example using your annotation without using the `MyValue` attribute generates this compiler error:

> annotation MyAnnotation is missing MyValue

Answer (score 12):

Given

```
public @interface MyAnnotation {
    int MyValue();
}
```

a class

```
@MyAnnotation
public class MyClass {

}
```

will be a compile error without a value.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried this but if you are wanting to force the values to a specific value perhaps making the type an enum.

```
public @interface MyAnnotation {
    Status status();
}
```

Where Status is an enum.